# Proof of the stronger Triangle Inequality $|x-z| \leq |x-y| + |y-z|$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I've been looking for proofs of this version of the triangle inequality and I can't seem to find them *anywhere*. Anyway, I decided to try to prove it myself. Let me know how I did.

*Proof*

Let $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$

By definition of absolute value, any $r_1, r_2 \in \mathbb{R}, |r_1-r_2|=$ max$\{-(r_1-r_2),r_1-r_2\}$ and $\pm (r_1-r_2) \leq |r_1-r_2|$

Then $x - z = x - y + y - z = (x-y) + (y-z) \leq |x-z| \leq |x-y| + |y-z|$

Thus, $|x-z| \leq |x-y| + |y-z| \hspace{1cm} \square$

---

The only ugly thing about this proof is that I can't find a good place to stick the $|x-z|$ in the last statement. On the one hand, $x-z = (x-y)+(y-z)$ and  $x-z \leq |x-z|$ so it's technically a true statement in the last line, but it still looks kinda ugly to say that $(x-y) + (y-z) \leq |x-z| \leq |x-y| + |y-z|$ in a proof.

Comment: This is equivalent to saying $|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$ for all $a,b,c$, so neither version is "stronger" in any sense than the other.

Comment: Oh it's definitely not stronger. I just haven't seen it called by any name so that's just what I've been calling it

Comment: $|x-z|=|(x-y)+(y-z)|\leq|x-y|+|y-z|$

Comment: well... both go by the name of triangle inequality, though for the purposes of proving, $|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$ is notationally simpler. Also, you seem to be adding in unnecessary steps. You can just say $(x-y)+(y-z)\leq |x-y|+|y-z|$ directly.